# Raspberry Pi and LCD screen

Tags: raspberry-pi, webcam, display, raspberry-pi3, lcd

I have a pi3 and I want to connect it to my monitor that came from my old computer. The problem is that it is a monitor and a webcam combined, and the cable is too wide for the connectors. I was wondering if I could use the gpio pins, and if so, which ones and how to connect it all.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect them using HDMI-DVI or HDMI-VGA converter.
I am assuming monitor cable to be DVI or VGA. If you can mention details of the cable, you can get precise answer.

Comment: It is long and thin. The kind that would be on the end of a ribbon cable. (It came out of a laptop)